# Dtexec /ConsoleLog option

Tags: ssis

I'm running an SSIS 2012 project in SSIS store using dtexec from the command line with a parameter file.

The command line is:

```
dtexec /cons /com param_file.txt
```

The package executes and completes, but the /cons parameter does not have any effect. Same result with and without it. Job submits and back to the command prompt.

I was expecting something like an execution log, not just a submission report. This is what I get:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:30:34 AM
Execution ID: 10087.
To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report
Started:  10:30:34 AM
Finished: 10:30:34 AM
Elapsed:  0.531 seconds
C:\SSIS\CDA>
```

Here are the contents of the param_file.txt (xxx in place of anything that the powers that be might object to being posted)

```
/ISSERVER "\SSISDB\CDA\xxx_Update\xxx_Updatexxx.dtsx"
/SERVER "xxx"
/Par $Project::Log_ServerName;"xxx"
/Par $Project::Log_InitialCatalog;"xxx"
/Par $Project::Log_UserName;xxx
/Par $Project::Log_Password;xxx
/Par RS_ServerName;xxx
/Par RS_InitialCatalog;xxx
/Par RS_UserName;xxx
/Par RS_Password;xxx
/Par CDA_ServerName;xxx
/Par CDA_InitialCatalog;xxx
/Par CDA_UserName;xxx
/Par CDA_Password;xxx
```

Comment: What happens if you add `/REP V` ?

Comment: /rep v didn't have any effect on what I see on the console

Comment: What's in the `param_file.txt`?  These can effectively override other command settings.